# Enviar email PHP consulta

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mail

Hola tengo una gran duda sobre el envió de correo por PHP.
he visto que en mis correo que envió sale la dirección del panel del hosting donde envió los correos. Ejemplo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar ademas de la información del nombre y el correo donde lo envió sale información adicional la cual es después del "a través de", he visto que en otros correos no sale esa información.
¿Como puedo ocultar o eliminar esa información de mis correos enviados por mi hosting de Godaddy?.

El código que utilizo es simple:

```
$para = "Aqui coloco el email a quien se lo enviare";
$asunto = 'Notificación';
$remitente = "no-reply@ejemplo.com";
$info = 'hola@ejemplo.com';
$headers = "From: Nombre <" . $remitente . "> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $info . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
$mensaje="El mensaje a enviar"
mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers);
```

Comment: Prueba a pasar un 5º parámetro a `mail`, algo así: `mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers, "-fusuario@example.com");` OJO, debe haber el signo `-` y una `f`. Para más detalles ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24213494/5587982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se muestra ahí es el parámetro `envelope-from` de la parte `Received` del correo electrónico.

Si exploras el código fuente del mensaje (opción `Mostrar original` en Gmail) verás algo como esto:

```
 Received: from usuarioDelHosting by box999.tuHosting.com with local
 (Exim 4.93) (envelope-from <usuarioDelHosting@box999.tuHosting.com>)
 id 1a4C8a-004Etz-6M for tu-email@example.com; Fri, 07 Aug 2020  17:51:00 -0600
```

Según el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) esa información se puede cambiar mediante los parámetros adicionales, que se pasan como un quinto parámetro a la función `mail()`:

> El parámetro `additional_parameters` puede usarse para indicar
> opciones adicionales como opciones de línea de comandos al programa
> que está configurado para usarse cuando se envía correo, definido por
> la opción de configuración `sendmail_path`. Por ejemplo, puede usarse
> para establecer la dirección de correo del remitente usando `sendmail`
> con su opción `-f`.

Aplicando lo dicho anteriormente, podrías añadir un quinto parámetro a `mail`, por ejemplo:

```
# ^ ... todas tus variables ^
# Agregamos en envelope-sender
$eSender="-f tuUsuario@tuDominio.com";
$mail=mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers,$eSender);
```

Ahora el código fuente de tu mensaje se verá así:

```
 Received: from usuarioDelHosting by box999.tuHosting.com with local
 (Exim 4.93) (envelope-from <tuUsuario@tuDominio.com>)
 id 1a4C8a-004Etz-6M for tu-email@example.com; Fri, 07 Aug 2020  18:05:03 -0600
```

Y en la información que ves en la interfaz gráfica debería verse algo como: *`A través de tuUsuario@tuDominio.com`*.

Ese parámetro se podría cambiar también desde `php.ini` de una forma definitiva, si conviene.

Para más detalles puedes consultar: [*How to change envelope from address using PHP mail?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179014/5587982)